# ProxyPass node relative URL

Tags: node.js, apache, apache2

I have a node application running on port `8000`. Here is my apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/multiplication/public

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location /multiplication>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
    </Location>

    # Log file locations
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  /var/log/multiplication.error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/multiplication.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I visit `mysite.com/multiplication` I want the node app to treat this as `mysite.com`. Currently, when I do this, my React router returns the error `app.js:85564 Warning: Location "/multiplication" did not match any routes`

What can I do?

Comment: you should use rewrite url with P flag, see more in some searches, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=proxypass+rewrite. Note this is a pure httpd problem.

Comment: @mh-cbon, if you could provide the answer, that would be great; I tried googling RewriteRule but couldn't find a solution that worked

Comment: Your config seems fine. Does accessing node directly work without errors?

Comment: The node application runs fine. It is the route that is causing an issue. The react router things I am on page `mysite.com/multiplication` but it is expecting the index page to load